# Usage of "be cut out for"

Tags: expressions

I found that the phrase "be cut out for" is used only in negative sentences (for example, "He's **not** cut out for teaching"). Is it true? Or can I make a statement like "I feel like I'm cut out for this job"?

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+out+for It can be used in a *positive* sense, too.

Comment: @NVZ: In principle you *could* use the idiom in non-negating contexts, but it would be so unusual OP is probably better off assuming it's "non-standard".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree. It's mostly not cut out for positive contexts.

Comment: It's not inherently negative but is probably used with a negative more often than not.

Comment: @Silenus: (hafta post here 'cos k1eran's post is deleted) I just looked at the first page of actual Google Books results for your [*definitely cut out for*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=definitely+cut+out+for%2Cdefinitely+not+cut+out+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdefinitely%20cut%20out%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdefinitely%20not%20cut%20out%20for%3B%2Cc0) NGram. 7 of the 10 hits are the sense of *You've definitely got your work cut out for you!* (i.e. - *You're facing a tough job here!*, a completely different idiomatic usage).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you're right! The Ngram is hopeless here. But at least those book results (and those on subsequent pages) validate the positive use. Now the interesting question is the relation between the "work cut out" idiom and the "I'm not cut out for this" idiom. Maybe one day someone will ask it!

Comment: @Silenus: I assume that ultimately both senses derive from the tailoring / seamstressing context. Your assistant (or boss) might prepare / cut out an excessive amount of cloth for you to deal with. Or he might have prepared the right pieces of cloth to make a *shirt*, in which case things will go badly wrong when you try to sew them up to make a pair of knickerbockers! :)

Answer (score 2):

The idiom ***be cut out for*** means

> "[USUALLY WITH NEGATIVE] have exactly the right qualities for a particular role, task, or job" ([Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/be-cut-out-for-or-to-be?q=be+cut+out+for)).

As you see, the dictionary notes that it is *usually* used in a negative formation. The example sentence is, in fact, negative: "I'm just *not* cut out to be a policeman."

Most native speakers would probably agree that the negative variation is the more standard one. They might even cringe at the positive variation (or at least raise an eyebrow).

But still, the positive variation is perfectly acceptable. In other words, it is perfectly fine to say: "He is cut out to be a policeman."

To see this, just consult the results [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22definitely%20cut%20out%20for%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1922,cd_max:2007&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl). But note that some of these results contain another idiomatic construction: "We ***have our work*** ***cut out for*** us", which means (roughly) "We're going to have a tough time with this work" ([here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+work+cut+out)). Although this idiom is mixed in with the results, the positive use of **be cut out for** is nonetheless present.